# Woocommerce remove an action hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin in my wordpress site. I want to remove a function named 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form' which is hooked in to the action 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form'.

I tried adding the below code in my theme functions.php

```
add_action('init','remove_coupon_text',10);
function remove_coupon_text() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','woocommerce_checkout_login_form',10);
}
```

But this is not working. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake from my side. I used the wrong function name. The function name I intended to remove was 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form'. The issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry it was a mistake from my side. I used the wrong function name. The function name I intended to remove was 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form'. The issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
remove_all_actions( $tag, $priority );
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: if remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart',10 ); doesnot work then you can try remove_all_actions( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10 );

Answer (score -2):

Try increasing the priority.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','woocommerce_checkout_login_form',1 - 10);
```

**Edit:** Follow the comments below and dont use this as it is, what i meant by increasing priority was to gradually increase the priority till it matches the time when function was added, when it does match you will automatically see the results else it just wont work. Thank you everyone for making it clear.

Comment: Codex says: "To remove a hook, the `$function_to_remove` and `$priority` arguments must match when the hook was added." http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: What it actually means is to have the same priority if the files are loaded in a correct manner, i.e woocommerce wc_hooks.php loads before your function. But if somehow your file is loading before woocommerce and then woocommerce is again adding the action, in that case having the same priority wont remove the action. So the solution to remove the action in that case will be to increase the priority of the request. Dont know if it fits your scenario but thats what the priority parameter is supposed to do.

Comment: A hook's priority corresponds to a numeric key in the global `$wp_filter` array. The priority in `remove_action` must be identical in order to be able to unset the targeted key value pair.

Comment: This answer adds valuable information by showing an important mistake and the commenters correcting it.